# How to skip comments in java when reading from a text file

Tags: java

What I'm trying to do is make it so that when the text file is read the comments within in the text file are ignored and not printed along will everything else.

This is the code I have atm and the first part which skips single line comments works however the second part where it tries to skip block comments just doesn't work and the following error message is given

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 186
> at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
> at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:712)
> at Q3.scan(Q3.java:281)
> at Q3.main(Q3.java:15)

Any help would be great. I can't really change the style of the way it currently is too much either

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Q3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("Q3Example1:");
        String prog1 = readFile2String("src/Q3Example1.txt");
        scan(prog1);
        
        System.out.println("\nQ3Example2:");
        String prog2 = readFile2String("src/Q3Example2.txt");
        scan(prog2);
            
        
        //fix block comments
        
    }
    
    /**
     * takes the input operator and finds the operator tokentype
     * @param ch is the current character
     * @return the corresponding tokentype
     */
    public static TokenType getOp(char ch) {
        
            TokenType t = null;
        
            if(ch == '+') t = TokenType.OP_ADD;
            else if (ch == '-') t = TokenType.OP_SUBTRACT;
            else if (ch == '*') t = TokenType.OP_MULTIPLY;
            else if (ch == '/') t = TokenType.OP_DIVIDE;
            else if (ch == '%') t = TokenType.OP_MOD;
            else if (ch == '<') t = TokenType.OP_LESS;
            else if (ch == '>') t = TokenType.OP_GREATER;
            else if (ch == '=') t = TokenType.OP_ASSIGN;
        
        return t;
        
    }
    /**
     * takes the input double operator and finds the Double operator tokentype
     * @param s is the double operator that is input 
     * @return the corresponding tokentype to the double operator 
     */
    public static TokenType getOp(String s) {
        
        
            TokenType t = null;
        
            if(s.equals("<=")) t = TokenType.OP_LESSEQUAL;
            if(s.equals(">=")) t = TokenType.OP_GREATEREQUAL;
            if(s.equals("==")) t = TokenType.OP_EQUAL;
            if(s.equals("!=")) t = TokenType.OP_NOTEQUAL;
                
        return t;
        
    }
    /**
     * takes the input character and finds the Symbol tokentype
     * @param ch is the current character at the index
     * @return the corresponding tokentype if it equals any of the symbol characters
     */
    public static TokenType getSymbol(char ch) {
    
        
            TokenType t = null;
        
            if(ch == '(') t = TokenType.LEFT_PAREN;
            else if (ch == ')') t = TokenType.RIGHT_PAREN;
            else if (ch == '{') t = TokenType.LEFT_BRACE;
            else if (ch == '}') t = TokenType.RIGHT_BRACE;
            else if (ch == '[') t = TokenType.LEFT_BRACKET;
            else if (ch == ']') t = TokenType.RIGHT_BRACKET;
            else if (ch == ';') t = TokenType.SEMICOLON;
            else if (ch == ',') t = TokenType.COMMA;
            
        return t;
        
        
    }
    /**
     * takes the input string and finds the Keyword tokentype
     * @param s the input string 
     * @return if the string equals any of the else if parameters the keyword tokentype is returned
     */
        public static TokenType getKeyword(String s) {
    
        
            TokenType t = null;
        
            if(s.equals("if")) t = TokenType.KEYWORD_IF;
            else if (s.equals("else")) t = TokenType.KEYWORD_ELSE;
            else if (s.equals("int")) t = TokenType.KEYWORD_INT;
            else if (s.equals("String")) t = TokenType.KEYWORD_STRING;
            else if (s.equals("public")) t = TokenType.KEYWORD_PUBLIC;
            else if (s.equals("class")) t = TokenType.KEYWORD_CLASS;
            else if (s.equals("void")) t = TokenType.KEYWORD_VOID;
            else if (s.equals("static")) t = TokenType.KEYWORD_STATIC;
        
        return t;
        
    }
        /**
         * takes the input string and finds the Klingon tokentype
         * @param s the input string
         * @return the corresponding tokentype for the string else null
         */
        public static TokenType getKlingon(String s) {
            
            TokenType t = null;
            
            if(s.equals("rItlh")) t = TokenType.KLINGON_PRINT;
            else if (s.equals("boq")) t = TokenType.KLINGON_ADD;
            else if (s.equals("boqha")) t = TokenType.KLINGON_SUBTRACT;
            else if (s.equals("boqegh")) t = TokenType.KLINGON_MULTIPLY;
            else if (s.equals("boqHaegh")) t = TokenType.KLINGON_DIVIDE;    
            
        return t;
            
    }
        /**
         * checks if the current character is a letter from a-z or A-Z 
         * @param ch input character
         * @return if character is a letter then isLetter returns true else false
         */
        public static boolean isLetter(char ch) {
            
            if(ch >='a' && ch<='z') return true; 
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') return true;
            else return false;
            
        }
        /**
         * this is a method for including special symbols within strings and checks if any of the input characters correspond to any of the else if branches
         * @param ch input character
         * @return either true or false depending on the input character
         */
        public static boolean isSpecialSymbol(char ch) {
            
            if(ch == ':')return true;
            else if(ch == '@')return true;          
            else if (ch == ',')return true;
            else if (ch == '?')return true;         
            else if (ch == '#')return true; 
            else if (ch == '$')return true; 
            else if (ch == '£')return true;
            else if (ch == '!')return true; 
            else if (ch == '^')return true; 
            else if (ch == '.')return true; 
            else if (ch == '~')return true; 
            
            else return false;
            
        }
        /**
         * This method just checks if it is a digit at the current index
         * @param ch input character
         * @return either true if it is a digit or false if its not
         */
        public static boolean isDigit(char ch) {
            
            if(ch >='0' && ch<='9') return true; 
            else return false;
        
        }
        /**
         * This checks for white space 
         * @param ch input character
         * @return true if there is whitespace or false if there isn't 
         */
        public static boolean isWhiteSpace(char ch) {
            
            if (ch == ' ')return true;
            else if(ch == '\t')return true;
            else return false;
        
        }
        /**
         * checks for a new line or a line break
         * @param ch input character
         * @return true if there is a line break or false if there isn't 
         */
        public static boolean isLineBreak(char ch) {
            
            if(ch == '\n') return true;
            else return false;
        
        }
        
        /**
         * reads the specified file
         * @param fname the required file name
         * @return the content of the file 
         */
        public static String readFile2String (String fname) {
            
            String content = null;
            try {
                
                content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fname)));
                
            } catch (IOException e){
                
                System.out.println("Fail to read a file");
            }
            
            return content;
            
        }
        /**
         * this takes the input string, reads it and assigns keywords, line numbers etc to each string, letter, mathematical sign 
         * @param prog the input string
         */
        public static void scan(String prog) {
            
            int n = prog.length(); // n = to the length of the string being scanned
            int index = 0;
            int linenumber = 1;
            
            while (index < n) { // while the current character is less than the total characters the loop will run 
                
                char ch = prog.charAt(index);
                char ch_next = ' '; 
                char ch_next2 = ' ';
                if (index < n-1) ch_next = prog.charAt(index+1);
                if (index < n-2) ch_next2 = prog.charAt(index+2);
                boolean blockComment;
                
                
                boolean whiteSpace = isWhiteSpace(ch);
                boolean newline = isLineBreak(ch);
                
                TokenType sym = getSymbol(ch);
                TokenType op = getOp(ch);               
                boolean letter = isLetter(ch);
                boolean digit = isDigit(ch);

                if (whiteSpace) { // if there is whitespace then it skips it and moves to the next character
                    
                    index++;
                    continue;
                    
                } else if (newline) {// if there is a new line then the line number is increased by one and the index increases by one
                    
                    linenumber++;
                    index++;
                    continue;
                    
                } else if(ch == '/' && ch_next == '/'){
                    
                    index++;
                    index++;
                    ch = prog.charAt(index);
                    
                    while(ch != '\n') {
                        index++;
                        ch = prog.charAt(index);
                        
                    }
                    continue;
                
                } else if(ch == '/' && ch_next == '*' && ch_next2 == '*'){
                    
                    blockComment = true; 
                    
                    index++;
                    index++;
                    index++;
                    
                    ch = prog.charAt(index);
                
                        
                    
                    while(blockComment) {
                        
                        index++;
                        
                        ch = prog.charAt(index);                    
                        if(ch == '*' && ch_next == '/') {
                            blockComment = false;
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    continue;
                        
                    
                } else if (sym != null) { // getSymbol is called and if it doesn't return null then this is carried out
                    
                    
                    System.out.println(linenumber + ", " + sym + ", " + ch);
                    index++; // the index is increased and the loop is continued to the next character
                    continue;
                    
                } else if (op != null || ch == '!') { // if getOp(ch) doesn't return null or the ch == ! then this is carried out
                    
                    String operator = "";   // string operator is made              
                    operator += ch;     // operator == the current character                        
                    index++;            // index increases by one to check the next character
                    
                    while (index < n) { // this while loop adds the next character onto the current character in operator
                        
                        ch = prog.charAt(index);
                        
                        operator += ch;
                        
                        if (getOp(operator) != null) { // if the string operator doesn't return null it means its a double operator so this is carried out and the while statement ends
                            
                             System.out.println(linenumber + ", " + getOp(operator) + ", " + operator);
                            break;
                            
                        } else if (getOp(operator) == null) // if the operator does return null when put into getOp(s) then it must be a single operator and so this branch is carried out
                            
                            index--; // the index is reduced by one to return it to the previous operator (the single operator) 
                            ch = prog.charAt(index); //ch is assigned to the current character so that it equals the single operator                        
                            System.out.println(linenumber + ", " + op + ", " + ch);
                                break;
                                
                        }
                    
                    index++; // index and continue to the next character
                    continue;
            
                } else if (letter) { // if the current character is a letter then this branch is executed 
                    
                    String word = "";   // similar to the last else if branch new string is made for the word               
                    word += ch; // the word is built up                 
                    index++;// move onto the next character 
                    
                    while (index < n) { // while the current index is less than the total the loop will continue 
                        
                        ch = prog.charAt(index);
                        
                        if (isLetter(ch) || isDigit(ch)) { // the loop takes the current letter and adds it onto the word until it hits something that isn't a letter and then stops
                            
                            word += ch;
                            index++;
                    
                        } else 
                            break;
                        
                        }
                            // once the word is made the word runs through the two methods getKeyword and getKlingon to find its tokentype
                        TokenType keyword = getKeyword(word); 
                        TokenType klingon = getKlingon(word);
                
                        // this checks which method didn't return null and if neither klingon or keyword returned a value then it is assigned the identifier tokentype 
                            if (keyword!= null) {
                                
                                System.out.println(linenumber + ", " + keyword +  ", " + word);
                                
                            } else if(klingon != null) {
                                
                                System.out.println(linenumber + ", " + klingon +  ", " + word);
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                System.out.println(linenumber + ", " + TokenType.IDENTIFIER +  ", " + word);
                                continue;
                            }
                            
                        
                    } else if (digit) {
                        
                        // the same process as the word builder 
                        
                    String number = ""; 
                    number += ch;
                    index++;
                    
                    while(index < n) {
                        ch = prog.charAt(index);
                        if(isDigit(ch)) {
                            
                            number += ch;
                            index++;
                            
                        } else break;
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println(linenumber + ", " + TokenType.INTEGER +  ", " + number); 
                        continue;
                        
                     
                        
                    } else if (ch == '\"') { // once a double quotation mark is encountered this string takes place
                    
                    String str = "";// new string made
                        str += ch;// current character is added to the current string
                        index++;// index increases by one
                        
                        while(index < n) { // this loop builds the string literal by adding characters as long as the index is less than the total string length 
                            ch = prog.charAt(index);
                            if(isLetter(ch)) { // all of these branches check for different types of letters symbols, spaces and the final  double quotation marks and adds them onto the string 
                                
                                str += ch;
                                index++;
                                
                            } else if (isSpecialSymbol(ch)) { 
                                
                                str += ch;
                                index++;
                                continue;
                                
                            } else if (isWhiteSpace(ch)) {
                                
                                str += ch;
                                index++;
                                continue;
                                
                            } else if (ch == '\"') {
                                
                                str += ch;
                                index++;
                                continue;
                            }
                            else break;
                            
                        }
                        //string is printed with the line number tokentype and the string itself 
                            System.out.println(linenumber + ", " + TokenType.STRING + ", " + str); 
                            
                    } else {
                    
                    index++;
                    continue;
                    
                }
                
                }
                                                                
            }
                                                                        
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Also include the sample input file and expected/current output inside your question, not as images.

Comment: try this:
make a boolean variable, and when you reach the beginning of a multi-block comment, set it to true, and while it is true continue to NOT print anything until you reach the end of the comment and set it to false

Answer (score 1):

To be honest i dont understand your code, so here some simple code.

**My Input:**

```
package de;

public class Test {
    // Ignore this
    /*
    ignore this
     */
    /*
     * Ignore this too
     */
    public void hey() {

    }
}
```

**My Code:**

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/test/java/de/Test.java"));

        boolean currentlyInComment = false;

        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            if(line.trim().startsWith("/*")){
                currentlyInComment = true;
            }

            if(!currentlyInComment && !line.trim().startsWith("//")){
                // Do your algorithmic stuff with line
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            if(line.trim().startsWith("*/") && currentlyInComment) {
                currentlyInComment = false;
            }

            line = reader.readLine();
        }
```

**My Output:**

```
package de;

public class Test {
    public void hey() {

    }
}
```

(So implement your code interpretation into this)

**What does this do?:**

I introduced a variable wether currently there is an comment. You have to set the boolean to false after working with the current line, because this line has to be ignored too.
Basically the programm recognizes comments by "/*" and then the end of a comment by "*/" and simple single line comments by "//". Every other line will be procceded.